# Spark Java error printing array list

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using Spark with Java to read a file from a text file that I store in documents.
Then I split the documents by line then by word.

But when I print the words I get

```js
[[Ljava.lang.String;@2819c460]
[[Ljava.lang.String;@30364216]
[[Ljava.lang.String;@38bb9d7a]
[[Ljava.lang.String;@1e8ab90f]
[[Ljava.lang.String;@78d6447a]
```

Below is my code

```js
JavaRDD<String> documents = sc.textFile(path, 1000);
        
        JavaRDD<ArrayList<String[]>> lines = documents.map(document -> {
         return document.split("\\r?\\n");
        }).map(_lines -> {


   ArrayList<String[]> parsedLines = new ArrayList<>();

   Arrays.asList(_lines).stream().parallel().forEach(line -> {
    parsedLines.add(line.split("\\t"));
   });
   return parsedLines;

        });

        lines.take(5).forEach(column -> {
          System.out.println(column);
        });
```

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(column)) gives me this error :

```js
Error:(62, 50) java: no suitable method found for toString(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]>)
    method java.util.Arrays.toString(long[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]> cannot be converted to long[])
    method java.util.Arrays.toString(int[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]> cannot be converted to int[])
    method java.util.Arrays.toString(short[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]> cannot be converted to short[])
    method java.util.Arrays.toString(char[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]> cannot be converted to char[])
    method java.util.Arrays.toString(byte[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]> cannot be converted to byte[])
    method java.util.Arrays.toString(boolean[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]> cannot be converted to boolean[])
    method java.util.Arrays.toString(float[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]> cannot be converted to float[])
    method java.util.Arrays.toString(double[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]> cannot be converted to double[])
    method java.util.Arrays.toString(java.lang.Object[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]> cannot be converted to java.lang.Object[])
```

Comment: You can't print an array directly (well you can, but then you just get something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@2819c460`) - but you can use `Arrays.toString(array)` like the duplicate explains to get to the contents of the array

Comment: Arrays.toString() doesn't work

Comment: I edited my post to show the error

Comment: Of course, you have a `List` of arrays, so you should call `Arrays.toString` on each element of the list.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Maybe should I use a for loop instead of foreach?

Comment: I managed to do it. Thank you. 
I just put .get(0) 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(column.get(0)));